# What is this lamp base wire clip and how do I remove the wire without breaking the clip?

Tags: wire, lamp, rewire

I'm trying to replace the socket in an old desk lamp, and I need to pull the wire through.  However, the wire is secured tightly by a black plastic clip at the base.    I'm wondering what this clip is called, and how to remove the wire without breaking the clip.  I would like to be able to reuse the clip (or buy a new one if I know what it's called and can find it).

[image: Base of lamp]
[image: Clip from outside of base]
[image: Clip from inside of base]

Comment: It's generically called a "grommet" or "bushing" -- do not know a brand name.  To remove it you (from the bottom) squeeze the two halves together with a pair of pliers, then push it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is a Heyco bushing. You need to squeeze, preferably with a needle-nose pliers, in what I would call a top-to-bottom position considering the orientation of how it is installed.

If you squeeze just right it will come out no problem and will not damage the cord.

Here is a decent video explanation: 
http://youtu.be/G1IWQB3mQrw

Here is the manufacturer's guide:
http://www.heyco.com/img/SR_Assembly_Guide.pdf

Rest assured, it CAN be done with a regular pliers if you're careful. I've done it a million times.

Also, keep in mind, to replace a socket you really should not have to remove that bushing if the cord is in good shape.

Comment: Often with this type of lamp it is necessary like the OP said to allow the cord to temporarily pull up through the top of the fixture to allow the socket to be removed / replaced.

Comment: That's why I said "should not have to". Of course it's possible, but after rewiring literally hundreds of lamps in my youth typically you do not.

Comment: Beautiful - thank you both.  Yeah, I was thinking I should be able to tug on the wire to get enough slack, but it's clamped on pretty good.  I will probably go ahead and replace the wire while I'm at it.  I would upvote both your answers but don't have enough reptuation yet :\

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - If your youth was as long ago as my youth it would be back when such lamps were actually made in the US and were designed to be serviced.

Answer (score 9):

Speedy's answer is an excellent one. I here want to add a picture of what these clips look like in the raw so that it is more apparent how they work.

[image]

The groves along the areas pointed to by the red lines are those that grip to the inside edge of the hole in the lamp base and retain the cord. When you squeeze the clip, as Speedy explains, the clip compresses enough to release the grooves from the inside edge of the hole in the lamp base.